# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: c#, smtp

This is the relevant code (C#)

```
                    MailMessage m;
                    SmtpClient client;   

                    client.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
                    client.Port = 465;  
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@yahoo.com", "mypassword");

                    m = new MailMessage();
                    m.From = new MailAddress("mymail@yahoo.com");
                    m.To.Add(new MailAddress("anothermail@gmail.com"));
                    m.Subject = "My subject";
                    m.Body = "This is my body. ";

                    client.Send(m);
```

This is the full error trace

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.BufferedReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at EmailSender.EmailSenderForm.send() in c:\Users\Ankur\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\EmailSender\EmailSender\EmailSenderForm.cs:line 91
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Yahoo doesn't allow 3rd party mail clients to operate their accounts. That's why you need webmail extensions with Thunderbird for example. Yahoo offers their Yahoo Mail Plus for these kind of services. Can you try your application with another mail account in Gmail? There it should work fine.

I have this code configured for an outlook account for sending emails. I have it working two years now without any modifications. It should work out of the box (just changing the account names):

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(@"example@hotmail.com",
                     dest, textBox1.Text, richTextBox1.Text);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"examplehotmail.com", "password");
client.EnableSsl = true;
messageSent = false;
client.SendAsync(mm, null);
client.SendCompleted += SentMessageTrigger;
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I dont have a Gmail but I do have a outlook account provided by school. Its settings look like this - http://i.imgur.com/q1ZEUPb.png . When I try the code with this account, I get the following error:

Comment: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 157.56.238.22:587

Comment: Well, I have configured outlook with different settings. For smtp I have the address `smtp.live.com` and it works. I have a code that do exactly what you want (send and email from c# with this class) configured with gmail. I'll check it but I strongly recommend gmail just to test because is the more *normal* mail account when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: Check my answer. I edited with code that uses a Hotmail account. Hope it works